# An App ID with Identifier is not available. Please enter a different string error for personal team

Tags: ios, ios9, xcode7, app-id, apple-id

I am using my Apple id(personal team) for my project. I am able to install on my ios device but when when my friend is trying to use my project with his apple id(personal team). He is getting this error "An App ID with Identifier is not available. Please enter a different string".

Soon we will purchase apple developer member program. but for now How should i configure bundle identifier so that we both use our own apple id.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem. Xcode7.2.1.
[image]

Effective solution is：
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears there *is* a logical answer to this issue. Apple has apparently gotten a bit more strict. So...

If your app's Bundle ID format is : com.my.app
**It should now be : com.my.app.XXX (e.g.: com.my.app.ios)**

Creating new App ID and provisioning profile will then fix the issue.

See the example in Apple's App Distribution Guide on Registering App IDs (Step 5). Note that the article as last edited on March 21, 2016, further implying this was a recent change causing this issue.

*Source: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/15712*

---

For those banging their heads on the wall trying to solve this issue *and you're running Xcode 7.3*...

While deleting and recreating all of the profiles in the Apple Developer's Member Center works for some (which I tried) as well as ylgwhyh's answer (which I tried as well), the only thing that worked for me was to:

**Downgrade from Xcode 7.3 to 7.2.1**

To do so:

1. Head to: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/ (must sign-in with your developer account)
2. Search for Xcode 7.2.1, right-click on the DMG (4.4 GB) and save to disk

I hope this helps anyone else trying to find a *logical* answer to an illogical problem...